# Im getting an Error running CocSearch in nvim

Tags: neovim, coc.nvim

Does any one know what this error means?

im getting this error when running:

```
:CocSearch query
```

Output:

```
[coc.nvim]: Error on "search": spawn rg ENOENT
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep, because CocSearch needs `rg` to do searching.